# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle v$parameter

Tags: sql-server

In Oracle we have a dynamic view v$parameter that lists the database parameters and their values.

Do we have an equivalent view or sys table or a procedure that gives similar data about SQLserver databases?

Comment: You might be looking for [`@@OPTIONS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177525.aspx) but it's tricky to tell. If you could say what specific setting/parameter you're interested in obtaining information about, there may be dedicated functions for accessing that.

Comment: You can use [sp_tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186250.aspx) to find out about tables or [sp_columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx) to find out information about the fields of a table or view. Or there is [sp_databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176070.aspx) if you need information about a database. And there's [sp_fkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175090.aspx) if you need information about foreign keys. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182764.aspx) for the most common system procedures.